# Underscore.js performance issue - Can i use _.defer

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, foreach, underscore.js

In an simple web app that i am building using underscore.js and jquery. For a list of all people ( js object ) I am filtering out list of all the places (js object) they visited. People list is a html table with a `td` having places image icon which on click displays list of all places they visited. **Icon needs to be shown only for people who have visited at the least one place**. The problem here is that people and places count comes around `2000`, `100`. So the code below executes `2000*100` combinations. The browser complains me of unresponsive script. Code is provided below

```
_.each(peopleList, function (person, index, list) {

    //filter the respective places for people
    var visitedPlaces = _.filter(places, function (place) {
        return place.PeopleId == person.Id;
    });

    if (_.isEmpty(visitedPlaces)) {
        $("a#" + place.PeopleId).remove();
    }
});
```

Dead simple isn't it. For each person check if visited places has him tracked. How do i optimize the above code to unblocking and responsive. Tried putting in `_.defer` and `_.delay` at some places but no improvement

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955976/how-can-i-defer-a-jquery-each-loop

Comment: @m90 thanks for the link will update answer if it solves my problem

Comment: What's `project.ProjectID`?

Comment: @Tomalak edited code. I check if the visitedPlaces is empty if yes then remove the link to view visited places for the person of concern

Comment: Can you tell the average length of the `visitedPlaces` for a set of 2000 people, 100 places?

Comment: @Tomalak Right now it is 100 :) , i am trying a solution using `_.defer` and `_.delay` not getting anywhere to solution

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, there are `N` people and `M` places, which makes for a potential number of visits `V` of `0 <= V <= M * N` (if everybody goes everywhere at most once). It's `V` that interested in. Also, I really think you won't get much performance improvement from underscore, `delay()` definitely won't help.

Comment: @Tomalak yep understood, will try out something else. Yours solves the problem, but then trying for more solutions

Comment: The underscore solution I created is quite fast as well, at least with your numbers - am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, here is how I would solve it in underscore.

```
function removeNonTravelers(people, visits) {
    var travelers    = _.pluck(visits, 'PeopleId'),
        nonTravelers = _.reject(people, function (person) {
            return _.contains(travelers, person.Id);
        });

    $(_.map(nonTravelers, document.getElementById)).remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FWzeN/

Comment: Superb and awesome, works like charm. Thanks for teaching me something today

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to drop underscore and use plain JS for this:

```
function removeNonTravelers(people, visits) {
    var i, peopleId,
        numPeople = people.length,
        numVisits = visits.length,
        index = {}, nonTravelers = [];

    // index
    for (i = 0; i < numVisits; i++) {
        peopleId = visits[i].PeopleId;

        if (!index.hasOwnProperty(peopleId)) {
            index[peopleId] = 1;
        } else {
            index[peopleId]++;
        }
    }

    // find HTML elements to remove
    for (i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {
        peopleId = people[i].Id;

        if (!index.hasOwnProperty(peopleId)) {
            nonTravelers.push(document.getElementById(peopleId));
        }
    }

    // remove them all at once
    $(nonTravelers).remove();
}
```

This is reasonably fast. If I didn't make any mistake, your test case (2000 people, 100 places) times at more than 700 operations per second on my rather outdated laptop (DOM operations excluded).

Try for yourself: http://jsperf.com/where-not-exists-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var hashMap = {};

_.each(places, function(place) {
  hashMap[place.PeopleId] = place;
});

_.each(peopleList, function (person, index, list) {

    //filter the respective project documents
    var visitedPlaces = hashMap[person.id];

    if (visitedPlaces) {
        $("a#" + place.PeopleId).remove();
    }
});
```