# Asynchronous update

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I use Easeljs to draw on a **large** canvas, with a **high** number of sprites. The drawing does not often occur, but when it does, it is a pretty slow process (about 1 or 2 seconds) which **halt** the web-application until it is finished.

Is there a way to make the update **asynchronous**, in a way that it does not slow down the browser?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13956264/797194

Comment: Not really. The heavy operation here is just a call to **one** function (namely, `easeljs.Stage.update()`).